# Grouping labels with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Is it possible to group inputs with simple_form?

I want "Postcode and city" to appear with one label and two inputs in one `div` as a group and not separately. But I cannot find a switch that turns off the label…

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off the label on one input with the `:label => false` option.

Like this:

`<%= f.input :name, :label => false %>`

Answer (score 1):

@rafaelfranca is right.

I am using Simple Form with an address like this:

```
<%= f.input :address, :placeholder => "Street + housenumber" %>
<%= f.input :zip, :label => false, :placeholder => "ZIP-code" %>
<%= f.input :locality, :label => false, :placeholder => "City/Town/Locality" %>
<%= f.input :state, :label => false, :placeholder => "State/Area" %>
<%= f.input :country, :label => false, :placeholder => "Country" %>
```

Then you will get only one label "Address" for the first text field. And all the next fields will show a placeholder.